# NETTY 4.1.4: TCP Socket Server which replies back towards clients after processing requests

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, netty

i'm new to Netty and intend to create a tcp socket server which reads the info of each client and replies back towards client before processing requests immediately ,i.e. sort of an acknowledgement towards client as and when the message enters overriden channelRead method of ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter class.

Please guide me in the above specified objective.
i'm currently trying the basic netty 4.1.4 echo server example however i wanted server to send back acknowledgement to the client so i updated channelread method as follows :

```
@Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ctx.write(msg);
        ChannelFuture cf = ctx.channel().write("FROM SERVER");
        System.out.println("Channelfuture is "+cf);
    }
```

and the output obtained was as follows:

```
Channelfuture is DefaultChannelPromise@3f4ee9dd(failure: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: String (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion))
```

I understand the error that it is expecting bytebuf but how do i achieve it? also, whether this method would be able to send out acknowledgement towards client

Comment: Do you need to use Netty 3, or is 4 an option?  Suggest looking at and playing with the examples. https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example

Comment: hi,
i just require a more stable version so chose netty 3. if any update from version 4 is stable i will choose it if needed.
i did look at few example and was able to understand few things.
however, i'm stuck in this simple thing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 3, but if you try it in 4 I might be able to help. According to Trustin from the Netty project 4.0 is stable and 3.x is deprecated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457648/different-netty-versions-and-their-purposes

Comment: i believe it is necessary to change my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.getBytes(Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byte[])](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer(byte[])) to convert to ByteBuf.

```
ChannelFuture cf = ctx.channel()
    .write(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("FROM SERVER".getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)));
```

Also note that `ctx.channel().write(...);` may not be what you want.  Consider `ctx.write(...);` instead.  The difference is that if your handler is a ChannelDuplexHandler it would receive a write event when you do `channel().write()`.  Using `ctx` instead of `channel` will send the write out from your handlers point in the pipeline instead of from the end of the pipeline, which is usually what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot chris.
i took your suggestion of using ctx instead of channel to write to client.

i had some other query as well, is the code below also be a sort of acknowledgement towards client?

    byte[] request = new byte[] { 0x01 };
    ctx.write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(request));

Comment: Not sure what you mean by acknowledgement. The original echo code acknowledges each read by writing back what it read and flushes when readComplete triggers.

Comment: okay. thanks for suggestions and explanations for steps provided by you
great help !

Comment: i actually thought that the acknowledgement either has to be some response sent towards client or the ACK{0x01} bytes sent out towards client in the tcp handshake process.
This object msg(as parameter) in method chnnelRead has to be the message which was sent from string however it is of type SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf.
how can i read it as a string? i've tried multiple way i.e. using getbytes. readablebytes method etc.
and it seems while reading we need to set some limit  for data read.
which is the best way to read data as a string

Comment: i found the workaround for same
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
     ByteBuf buff = (ByteBuf) msg;
     byte[] bytes;
     int offset;
     int length = buff.readableBytes();

     if (buff.hasArray()) {
         bytes = buff.array();
         offset = buff.arrayOffset();
     } else {
         bytes = new byte[length];
         buff.getBytes(buff.readerIndex(), bytes);
         offset = 0;
     }
     
     String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED "+str);

Comment: You may want to check out this answer for a simpler method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40291978/2097751

Comment: hi chris, Can you guide me with this issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767974/exception-java-nio-channels-notyetconnectedexception-for-a-socket-client-with-n

Comment: Hi chris,
i was facing an issue of channelReadComplete() method being called twice with one client connected. To resolve the issue i used ctx.close() in same method, however i doubt that it may cause performance issues.
i need to know about netty, ctx.close() closes the channels , however when the same client tries to write to server, will it take more time than the case where i ddin't close the channel.?